# String Encrypted Type of JSONType changes are not saved to Database

Tags: python, encryption, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

**Backstory**

I have a questionnaire that asks sensitive questions most of which are true/false. The majority of the time the values are false which poses a challenge when keeping the data private at rest. When encrypting  each question into a separate column, it is really easy to tell which value is true and which is false with a bit of guessing. To combat this, the questions and answers are put into a dictionary object with some salt (nonsense that changes randomly) then encrypted. Making it impossible without the key to know what the answers were.

**Method**

Below is an example of the model used to encrypt the data with salt at rest making it impossible to look at the data and know the contents.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_utils.types import JSONType
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import StringEncryptedType, AesEngine


Base = declarative_base()

class SensitiveQuestionnaire(Base):
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    _data = data: dict = sa.Column(StringEncryptedType(JSONType, 'secret', AesEngine, 'pkcs5'),
        nullable=False, default=lambda: {'_salt': salt_shaker()})

    # values are viewed using a python property to look into the `_data` dict
    @property
    def sensitive_question(self) -> Optional[float]:
        return self._data.get('sensitive_question')

    # values are set into the `_data` dict
    @sensitive_question.setter
    def sensitive_question(self, value: bool) -> None:
        self._data['sensitive_question'] = value

    # in a real example there would be 20+ properties that map to questions

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Sqlalchemy does not use the __init__ method so we are free to set object defaults here
        self._data = {'_salt': salt_shaker()}
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    @property
    def _salt(self) -> str:
        return self._data['_salt']


def salt_shaker():
    return ''.join([random.choice('hldjs..' for i in range(50)])
```

**The Problem**

After the `SensitiveQuestionnaire` object is initialized none of the changes are persisted in the database.

```py
# GIVEN a questionnaire 
questionnaire = model.SensitiveQuestionnaire(user_id=1)
db.session.add()
db.session.commit()

# WHEN updating the questionnaire and saving it to the database
questionnaire.sensitive_question= True
db.session.commit()

# THEN we get the questionnaire from the database
db_questionnaire = model.SensitiveQuestionnaire.query\
                   .filter(model.SensitiveQuestionnaire.user_id == 1).first()

# THEN the sensitive_question value is persisted
assert db_questionnaire.sensitive_question is True
```

Value from the `db_questionnaire.sensitive_question` is `None` when it should be `True`.

Answer (score 3):

After spending the better part of the day to figure this out, the cause of the issue is how Sqlalchemy knows when there is a change. The short version is sqlalchemy uses python's `__setitem__` to hook in sqlalchemy's `change()` method letting it know there was a change. More info can be found in sqlalchemy's docs.

The answer is to wrap the `StringEncryptedType` in a `MultableDict` Type

> **Mutation Tracking**
>
> Provide support for tracking of in-place changes to scalar values, which are propagated into ORM change events on owning parent objects.
> From SqlAlchemy's docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/mutable.html

**Solution**

Condensed version... wrapping the StringEncryptedType in a `MutableDict`

```py
_data = data: dict = sa.Column(
        MutableDict.as_mutable(StringEncryptedType(JSONType, 'secret', AesEngine, 'pkcs5')),
        nullable=False, default=lambda: {'_salt': salt_shaker()})
```

Full version from the question above

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict
from sqlalchemy_utils.types import JSONType
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import StringEncryptedType, AesEngine


Base = declarative_base()

class SensitiveQuestionnaire(Base):
    user_id: int = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # The MutableDict.as_mutable below is what changed!
    _data = data: dict = sa.Column(
        MutableDict.as_mutable(StringEncryptedType(JSONType, 'secret', AesEngine, 'pkcs5')),
        nullable=False, default=lambda: {'_salt': salt_shaker()})

    @property
    def sensitive_question(self) -> Optional[float]:
        return self._data.get('sensitive_question')

    # values are set into the `_data` dict
    @sensitive_question.setter
    def sensitive_question(self, value: bool) -> None:
        self._data['sensitive_question'] = value

    # in a real example there would be 20+ properties that map to questions

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._data = {'_salt': salt_shaker()}
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    @property
    def _salt(self) -> str:
        return self._data['_salt']


def salt_shaker():
    return ''.join([random.choice('hldjs..' for i in range(50)])
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Very helpful for all of us following in your footsteps.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad you were able to find it and its useful